# Why if the antecedent P is false, and the consequence Q true, then the implication P $\Rightarrow$ Q is true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that that's the definition but I wonder why logicians choose that thefinition to be true. It sounds strange to me and I cant make sense of it if someone tell me 'if the sky is red, then I'm Marco Polo'.

Comment: This has been asked a few times on this site before and some of the users gave very intuitive explanations, but I can't find those questions with the search right now.  Somebody will though.  ETA: searching for "if p then q" gives several explanations, but I couldn't find the specific ones I remember.

Comment: [Relevant](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/implication.html)

Comment: Also [In classical logic, why is $(p⇒q)$ True if $p$ is False and $q$ is True?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-p-is-false-and-q-is-tr?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the [principle of explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).

We usually think of implications as promises. Suppose I always say the truth, and suppose I say: "if it's sunday, then I'll take my dog for a walk". If I take my dog for a walk in a saturday, did I break the promise?, **no!**, I only break my promise if it is sunday and I haven't taken my dog out.

Secondly, this very same example helps understanding the equivalence with the contrapositive ($p\Rightarrow q \iff ¬q \Rightarrow ¬p$): if I haven't taken my dog for a walk, that implies it's not sunday.

And, lastly, a phrase from [von Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann) fits perfectly (and I paraphrase): *in mathematics, one doesn't understand objects, one just gets used to them*. In Enderton's [A mathematical introduction to logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520), he suggests that we shouldn't really care about the relation with the way we define implication (or equivalence, or conjugation) with the way we usually understand it in our everyday life; we should just study the objects *per se*, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding what he says.

Comment: The person you're looking for is von Neumann. I think your interpretation of implication via its contrapositive is the most natural and clears up any misconceptions. It's a shame that more professors don't teach it this way. The phrase I like to use is "when can you call me a liar?" Then it's pretty obvious what the truth table must be.

Comment: Thanks, Cameron. And as a colombian saying goes: "If my aunt had wheels, she'd be a bus".

Comment: Hah that's a pretty good saying. I like that a lot. I might use that in the future when explaining $\Rightarrow$.