# Explanation of $A \to B = \neg A \lor B$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Can anybody explain intuitively why the logical implication $A \to B$ is equivalent to $$ \neg A \lor B$$

?

If e.g. $A$  is "It rains." and $B$ is "The street is wet.", then obviously $A$ implies $B$. Why is this the same as "It doesn't rain or the street is wet."?

Comment: Also: [In classical logic, why is $p\Rightarrow q$ true if $p$ is false and $q$ is true?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-p-is-false-and-q-is-tr)

Comment: It's a bit easier if you see it as $\lnot(A\land \lnot B)$. In that case, it means "It is not (never) the case that it rains and the street is not wet".

Comment: It either doesn't rain or it does. If it rains, the street is wet. Therefore, it either doesn't rain or the street is wet.