# Is $A \to \neg A$ logically satisfiable if $A$ is false?

Tags: propositional-calculus

Is it true that the implication $A \to \neg A$ is logically satisfiable if $A$ is false?

I beg your pardon if it is trivial but my logic is rusty.

Comment: $A \to \neg A$ is equivalent to $\neg A$.

Comment: Therefore I think it is not a contradiction.

Comment: It's merely a funny way of writing negation.

Comment: Recall that implication preserves truth. Hence, $\top \to \bot$ is false but $\bot \to \top$ is true, i.e., we have negation.

Comment: Yes.   $p\implies q$ is true if i) $p$ is true and $q$ is true; ii) $p$ is false.  And $p\implies q$ is false if and only if $p$ is true and $q$ is false.  So if $A$ is false then $A\implies \lnot A$ is true.  But if $A$ is true then $A\implies \lnot A$ is false.  So $A\to \lnot A \iff \lnot A$.

Answer (score 3):

$A\rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg A\lor B$ by definition, so $A\rightarrow \neg A\iff \neg A\lor \neg A\iff \neg A,$ which is true if and only if $A$ is false.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is true that
$$A \Longrightarrow \neg A$$
is satisfiable if $A$ is false. In fact, this is know as "vacuously true". We say a if-then statement, say $A \Longrightarrow B$, is false only when $A$ is true and $B$ is false. However, this question has already been asked multiple times: [“false implies true” is a true statement [duplicate]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583209/false-implies-true-is-a-true-statement)

Comment: It is more correct to say "is satisfiable if A *can* be false", because "satisfiable" means there is at least one model which makes the statement true.

Answer (score 3):

The truth table for $P \to Q$ is

$P =TRUE; Q=TRUE$ then $P\to Q = TRUE$

$P = TRUE; Q=FALSE$ then $P\to Q = FALSE$

$P = FALSE; Q=TRUE$ then $P\to Q=TRUE$

$P = FALSE; Q=FALSE$ then $P\to Q = TRUE$.

.....

So if $A$ is false then ... $A=FALSE$ and $\lnot A = TRUE$ and $A\to \lnot A = TRUE$.

.....

A good rule of thumb is:

If $P$ is false then

$P\to X$ is always true no matter what $X$ is.  So if $A$ is false than $A\to X$ is always true, even if $X = \lnot A$.

.....

Another rule of thumb is:  If $Q$ is true then

$X \to Q$ is always true no matter what $X$ is.  So if $A$ is false then $\lnot A$ is true.

So $X \to \lnot A$ is always true no matter what $X$ is; even if $X = A$.

....

Another rule of thumb (although not directly applicable here) is

The only way for $P \to Q$ to be false is if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.  Any thing else... then $P \to Q$ is true.

......

It may seem weird but when you get used to it

$P\to Q \equiv (\lnot P)\lor Q$

So so $A\to \lnot A$ is true if either $\lnot A$ is true or..... $\lnot A$ is true....