# Why is $p{\implies}q$ defined to have a truth value if $p$ is false?

Tags: logic

At first it would seem that if $p{\implies}q$ means "$p$ implies $q$", then if $p$ is false then the entire statement doesn't make sense. It looks like if we have no way of knowing whether $p$ implies $q$ or not, since $p$ was never a real thing in the first place. It would seem that the statement wouldn't have either "true" or "false" value, but rather "undecided".

Why did mathematicians decide to give this statement a "false" value?

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/

Comment: The meaning of the implication is that $T\implies F$ is excluded. The other combinations raise no objection, hence the expression is true, and this is harmless. Adding a third logical value would be extremely costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a special case of something called "vacuous truth", and it makes a lot more sense if you slightly change how you think about $p \implies q$.

For instance, look at the statement

> $\forall$ persons$($That person is from Holoshandra$\implies$That person speaks fluently English$)$

You *could* interpret it litterally, which would make the statement nonsensical, since there is no such place as Holoshandra. I choose to look at it as a promise. The statement can be rephrased into "Show me a person from Holoshandra, and I promise you that he speaks fluent English". That is a promise I am guaranteed to be able to keep (you can't give me a counterexample; there is no one from Holoshandra that *doesn't* speak English), and thus the statement is considered true.

Also consider the contrapositive:

> $\forall$ persons$($That person doesn't speak English$\implies$That person is not from Holoshandra$)$

which is more intuitively obvious, no matter what you mean by $\implies$.