# Ex falso quodlibet - $ z>1\Rightarrow z>3$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

$z>1\Rightarrow z>3$

this is a really simple example to help me understand.

So, if $z\in \mathbb{R}$, then when LHS is false, the statement is true.

But if LHS is true AND RHS is true $\Leftrightarrow$ the statement is false.

Is this right?

Comment: Almost duplicate: [In classical logic, why is (p⇒q)
True if p
is False and q
is True?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-p-is-false-and-q-is-tr)

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, i know it is almost surely a duplicate of some question, but i needed some "direct" assistance. If i can myself link to a dupliate i will do (please say the code for here)

Comment: i voted myself to close it because duplicate. so if nessecary do it too :) (i dont grief about it)

Comment: The only case when your implication is false, is when the lhs is true, AND the rhs is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not right: the only way a sentence "$A\implies B$" is false is if $A$ is *true* and $B$ is *false*. E.g. the sentence $$1+1=2\implies 3=87$$ is false, but $$3=87\implies 1+1=2$$ is true.

Comment: oh man, if i werent wasted i didnt made that mistake, but thanks anyways, thats exactly what i wanted to know :)$\\$ i edited my originial question, but your answer is till ok ;)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a real life example. Mr. X says," If my brother wears a white shirt then so do I".

Take $p$: Brother of Mr. X wears a white shirt.

$q$: Mr. X wears a white shirt.

Symbolically, it is the conditional  $p\implies q$.

On some day,  Mr. X  must feel guilty of lying about his past statement(i.e. conditional $p\implies q$ is $F$) if he will not be able to wear a white shirt ($q$ is $F$) whenever his brother will be wearing a white shirt ($p$ is $T$).