# Non-symmetrical relation: a mistake while asserting "not implies" with increasing levels of "strength"?

Tags: logic, relations, symmetry

In [this section of video from a book group I'm following](https://youtu.be/pbTnrbFLaIs?t=620) we consider the lack of symmetry of the relation $\lt$ on $\mathbb{R}$. The condition for symmetry, which does not hold, would look like this

$$
\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a < b \implies b < a \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

The video then offers three ways that this condition is negated, in increasing strength of the negation:

$$\begin{align}
\exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}&, a\lt b \,\,\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies b\lt a \tag{2}\label{eq2} \\
\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}&, a\lt b \,\,\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies b\lt a \tag{3}\label{eq3} \\
\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}&, a\lt b \implies \lnot(b \lt a) \tag{4}\label{eq4}
\end{align}$$

(The video explains that the notation $P \,\,\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies Q$ is the same as $\lnot(P\implies Q)$.)

I can immediately understand that $\eqref{eq2}$ is a simple negation of $\eqref{eq1}$. I can then understand how each statement that follows is a stronger negation: the existential quantifier is replaced by the universal in $\eqref{eq3}$, and then *not implies* is replaced by *implies not* in $\eqref{eq4}$.

However, is $\eqref{eq3}$ a true statement? The video suggests that $\eqref{eq1}$ is false, while $\eqref{eq2}$, $\eqref{eq3}$ and $\eqref{eq4}$ are true. I agree except that I've come to think that $\eqref{eq3}$ is false. I'm not confident that my reasoning (see below) is correct and would appreciate either some reassurance or a correction.

---

#### How I arrived at this question

I was immediately interested in whether one of $\eqref{eq3}$ or $\eqref{eq4}$ was equivalent to saying that $\lt$ is [antisymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation). After some reading on Wikipedia, I discovered that $\eqref{eq4}$ is a statement of [asymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_relation) (a stronger condition), and so then I wondered if that leaves $\eqref{eq3}$ as a statement of the weaker [antisymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation). When I failed to understand how $\eqref{eq3}$ might be related to the definition of antisymmetry given in Wikipedia, I realised I didn't understand *not implies* ($\,\,\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies$) very well, so I searched for information on negation of implication.

From reading [What is the negation of the implication statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417770/) I learned I could use

$$\lnot(P\implies Q) \iff P\land\lnot Q$$

to modify $\eqref{eq2}$ and $\eqref{eq3}$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}&, a\lt b \land \lnot(b\lt a) \tag{2*}\label{eq2'} \\
\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}&, a\lt b \land \lnot(b\lt a) \tag{3*}\label{eq3'} 
\end{align}$$

While $\eqref{eq2'}$ seems fine, I think $\eqref{eq3'}$ is false. Surely $a$ is not less than $b$ for all $a$ and $b$. Have I made a mistake, or is statement $\eqref{eq3}$ actually false?

Comment: $<$ is both an antisymmetric and asymmetric relation.

Comment: $P\not\!\!\!\implies Q$ is non-standard notation. If it means $\lnot(P\implies Q),$ then that is true only if $\lnot Q$ and $P$ are true, and you are correct, this is not true in your case. But it really depends on what $P\not\!\!\!\implies Q$ means.

Comment: But I can't think of a meaning for the notation that makes both $(2)$ and $(3)$ accurate.

Comment: Edited to try to clarify the non-standard notation - thanks @Thomas

Comment: The negation of $P$ is $\lnot P$. Thus, (2) is the negation of (1). And (2) and (2*) are fine.

Comment: (3) implies (2); thus, we can say that if (3) holds, than (1) does not.

Comment: I understand your analysis to be correct @Mauro. I've added some clarification about which statements I believe are true and false. I'm not so much interested in (1), it's just the motivation for how I got to be looking at (2), (3) and (4). My question is just about whether (3) is false. Have I properly shown that (3*) is false, that (3*) follows from (3) and that therefore (3) is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The video then offers three ways that this condition is negated, in
> increasing strength of the negation:
>
> \begin{align} \exists a,b \in \mathbb{R}&, a\lt b\,\,\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies b\lt a \tag{2}\\ \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}&, a\lt b \,\,\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies b\lt a\tag{3} \\ \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}&, a\lt b \implies\lnot(b \lt a) \tag{4}\end{align}

Since a sentence and its [negation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4518468/21813) must have opposite truth values *regardless of context* (that is, they logically contradict each other), **that claim/concept of increasing strength of negation is dubious**. For example, consider the sentences $P,Q,R$ such that $R$ is a logical consequence of $Q$ but not vice versa and $Q$ is a logical consequence of $P$ but not vice versa:

- suppose that $\lnot Q$ is true; then $P$ and $Q$ are both false but $R$ can be either true or false
- suppose that $\lnot Q$ is false, then $Q$ and $R$ are both true but $P$ can be either true or false

hence, only $Q$—but neither $P$ nor $R$—definitely has the opposite truth value of $\lnot Q.$

Among our sentences $(2), (3)$ and $(4),$ the only logical-entailment relationships (out of six possible permutations) are: $$(3)\models(2)\\(3)\models(4).$$

> The video suggests that $(1)$ is false, while $(2)$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ are true.

Then the video is wrong: while both $(2)$ and $(4)$ turn out to be mathematically true, the counterexample $(a,b)=(0,0)$ shows that $(3)$ is mathematically false.

---

The video's notion of negation strength may be a misplacement of the idea that [**non-implication (similarly: implication) can be asserted at various levels of logical strength**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4252038/21813).

---

> I think $(3)$ is false. Surely $a$ is not less than $b$ for all $a$ and $b$.

Exactly.

> Have I properly shown that (3*) is false, that (3*) follows from (3) and that therefore (3) is false?

Correction: the conclusion in your last clause results from (3*) and (3) **being equivalent** rather than from (3*) **merely following from** (3).

P.S. I usually understand $$Px{\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies} Qx$$ as a shorthand for the existential quantification $\;\exists x\:(Px\land \lnot Qx),\,$ so $$\forall a{,}b{\in} \mathbb{R} \;(a\lt b{\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies }b\lt a)\tag3$$ is quite unusual to parse.

Comment: Thank you - this exactly answers my question. I was surprised to learn that $(3)\models (4)$ but I think I follow why it's the case. It's so surprising because in the informal context it really does feel like $(4)$ should be "stronger" than $(3)$. I wonder if the informal interpretation of $P \,\,\,\,\not\!\!\!\!\implies Q$ is not, despite what I said, the same as $\lnot(P\implies Q)$. I also wonder how, in the discussion on levels of logical strength that you linked, would $\models\forall x\,\big( A(x)\to \lnot B(x)\big)$, i.e. (LUIN), fit in. Maybe that becomes another question one day...

Comment: @JustATrick I had the same thoughts as you! If $$∀x\,(Px{\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies}\lnot Qx)\:\models\:∀x\,(Px{\implies}Qx)$$ feels surprising, is it because we are inclined to misread the LHS as $$∃x\,(Px{\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies}\lnot Qx)\quad?$$ And if $$(P{\implies}Q)\;\not\models\;(P{\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies}\lnot Q)\\
∀x\,(Px{\implies}Qx)\;\not\models\;∃x\,(Px{\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies}\lnot Qx)$$ feel surprising, then vacuous truth is the likely culprit. $\tag*{}$ Re: that linked discussion, UNI is a special case of UIN, while LUNI is a special case of LUIN !