# Does this means that "anything" implies $T$?

Tags: logic

I'm reading Yves Nievergelt's Logic, Mathematics and Computer Science. Here:

> [image]

I am *very* confused about this. I understand the proof, but does that mean that anything implies $T$? Supposing my interpretation is correct, isn't it weird that anything implies $T$?

Comment: Well, what would be an example of something you think shouldn't imply $T$?

Comment: Not quite this question, but potentially enlightening: [In classical logic, why is $p\Rightarrow q$ True if $p$ is False and $q$ is True?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-p-is-false-and-q-is-tr)

Answer (score 6):

Semantically, to assert $S\Rightarrow T$ is the same as asserting that it is impossible for $S$ to be true and at the same time $T$ is false.

When $T$ is a theorem, it means that we know that $T$ *is actually true*. So the only situation that could *prevent* $S\Rightarrow T$ from being true is impossible right out of the gate -- we don't even need to look at $S$. Therefore $S\Rightarrow T$ *cannot be false*, so it must be true, and therefore it ought to be a theorem.

Comment: But does that mean that we could find a proof that $S\implies T$, for any $S$?

Comment: @BillyRubina Yes,  *if* $T$ is provable, then $S\to T$ is too, whatever $S$ may be.

Comment: @BillyRubina: Yes, and the argument you show in the question tells you exactly how to construct that proof.

Answer (score 2):

The hypothesis is that $T$ is a theorem ("for each well-formed formula $S$ and **each theorem** $T$"). This means that we have a proof of $T$ from nothing at all (that is, $\vdash T$). Adding hypotheses doesn't make things harder, so that same proof is a proof of $T$ from $S$, whatever $S$ is.

So **yes**, a $T$ of the type described in the theorem is provable from any $S$ whatsoever. Put another way, if $T$ is a theorem then $(S)\implies (T)$ is also a theorem for any (well-formed) $S$.

Answer (score 2):

> I am very confused about this. I understand the proof, but does that mean that anything implies T? Supposing my interpretation is correct, isn't it weird that anything implies T?

It is not weird.   If $T$ is indeed true, then surely that *anything* should imply that it is true.

$S\to T$ can be interpreted as : $T$ is true whenever $S$ is true.   That should be true when $T$ be guaranteed to be true, *whatever* $S$ may be.