# Understanding the truth value for ⇏ when antecedent is false and consequent is true.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am currently doing the Intro to Mathematical Thinking course on Coursera.

A quiz therein, asks:

> For what truth values of Φ and Ψ do we define Φ ⇏ Ψ to be T (true)?

It says the right answer is Φ is true and Ψ is false.  I understand that; but I do not follow why the reverse is not right. That is, why does Φ false and Ψ true does not make the statement Φ ⇏ Ψ to be true.  I am confused because if Ψ is true while Φ is false, the truth of Ψ does not follow from the truth of Φ and so it should be that Φ ⇏ Ψ.

Could someone please explain?

[image: Screenshot from the quiz]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you, @Shaun. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your text defines $\not\Rightarrow$ in such a way that
$\Phi\not\Rightarrow\Psi$ has the same meaning as
$\lnot(\Phi\Rightarrow\Psi)$.

Do you understand that $\Phi\Rightarrow\Psi$ is true when
$\Phi$ is false and $\Psi$ is true?
See [In classical logic, why is $(p\Rightarrow q)$ True if $p$ is False and $q$ is True?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-p-is-false-and-q-is-tr)

When $\Phi\Rightarrow\Psi$ is true, we must have that
$\lnot(\Phi\Rightarrow\Psi)$ is false, not true.