# On logical connector implies

Tags: logic

It may appear at first glance that this question had been asked over and over here. But I feel that the question that is in my mind is slightly different from what has already been asked. Here it is:

> What would have happened if $P \implies Q$ was taken false when $P$ was false and $Q$ was true?

I read several answers for the question: "Why false implies True is false?". I could gather some information from the answers. One is that irrespective of the truth value of $Q$, if $P$ is false, we treat $P \implies Q$ to be true vacuously. But this didn't answer my question, what would have happened if I had taken it to be false?
Another answer, which though addressed my question, I wasn't much satisfied with. This was that answer: If we had taken false implies true to be false, then truth tables of $\implies$ and $\leftrightarrow$  would have been one and the same.

Any answer in the direction of consequence of false implies true false is highly appreciated. I mean, would there have been any logical fallacy, contradiction or paradox of so kind if I had assumed false implies true to be false?

Comment: Essentially, you’d be changing the language of mathematics. It won’t change the meaning of the underlying logic, only the way we choose to express it. We don’t get new theorems, just (arguably clunkier) ways to express existing theorems. For example, instead of saying “If an integer $n$ Is divisible by $4$, then it is even”, I’d have to say something like “An integer is not divisible by $4$ or it is even” instead.

Comment: Yes, already discussed many times... See e.g. the post [What is the relation between the material conditional in logic and conditionals that we use every day?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14549/what-is-the-relation-between-the-material-conditional-in-logic-and-conditionals) as well as [Why do people use the material implication over alternatives?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/69411/why-do-people-use-the-material-implicaton-over-alternatives)

Comment: "What would have happened if P⟹Q was taken false when P was false and Q was true?" Nothing "catastrophic"... we have simply that $P \to Q$ and $P \leftrightarrow Q$ will be the same.

Comment: The current truth-functional definition of "if P, then Q" is of paramount relevance for mathematics **in connection with** [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens).

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4401689/21813), I pointed out how your proposed re-definition would render the statement "Every multiple of $4$ is even" _false_, which is surely undesirable.

Comment: I'm wondering if you may be more interested in proof theory, deduction rules, or something like mathematical constructivism based on some of the context. The implication (ha) in the question seems to be less about the structure of truth tables and propositional logic than it is about truth itself, which might be better served by looking at something like proof theory?

Comment: @NotAGenie It seems so!

Comment: @ryang I had missed that really. Thanks again for your concern. I was thinking on it. Yes it is reasonable to expect that the statement 'If today is Saturday and tomorrow is tuesday then today is Saturday' to be true. And that was what I was looking for. Thank you again.

Comment: @ryang Probably, I should have asked the question: 'if I set false implies true is false, would it then defy our any everyday logical sense'. The links provided by you seem to answer the above question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawing out a truth table makes it easy to see this.
$$\begin{array}{ccc} P & \implies & Q \\ \hline 
F & T & F \\ F & F & T 
\\T & F & F \\ T & T & T \end{array}$$

Nothing more and nothing less than the equivalence operator.

Comment: This, of course, would introduce all kinds of annoying inconsistencies in propositional logic. The truth table for implication can be derived from "first principles" one or more which would have to be disallowed or somehow restricted in their application. See my blog posting on this topic: https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2017/12/28/if-pigs-could-fly/

Comment: It occurred to me that "if $n$ is an even integer then $2n$ is an even integer" would cause problems in OP's world: setting $n = 3$ would then result in $2n$ being odd.

Answer (score 11):

You're not going to get anything like a logical paradox or anything because the way you are considering defining it is not self-contradictory. In fact, as @Prime Mover and you both point out, this would make it equivalent to $\Leftrightarrow$.

Nevertheless, this would lead to what would probably be considered an unsatisfactory operator. For example, "$x < 5 \Rightarrow x < 10$" would be false which is not what we want from an "if ... then ..." statement.

Comment: I cannot agree with if $x<5$ then $x<10$ example as I feel that this has been formulated forcibly so as to justify my choice of 'true'. 'If $\textit{it}$ then $\textit{that}$' is of no interest whenever $\textit{it}$ is false. If there are no contradictions and if  I get something equivalent to $\leftrightarrow$, then how can justify the necessity of $\implies$?

Comment: Sure. But, the thing is, we don't need either of $\Rightarrow$ or $\Leftrightarrow$. We can do both of them, indeed all of propositional logic, using use $\neg$ (not) and $\vee$ (or). So, you aren't going to find a justification in the form of logical necessity - all justifications are in the form of how useful it is or how well it jibes with our everyday use.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you.

Comment: @roundsquare: In fact, only *one* logical operator (either NAND or NOR) can generate all possible Boolean functions.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably more of a comment on @Dan's answer, but I feel I have something important to say so I'm making it an answer.

The first thing to be clear about is that the truth table for implication is a **definition**.  In other words, it is not a statement about the real world, but a statement about how we intend to use language.  Or in other words again: it is not something which has to be true, but something which we mean to be convenient, something that matches our intuitive conception of "if... then".

So, what features characterise our intuitive understanding of "if... then"?  Probably the most important is

- given the statement "if $p$ then $q$" and the statement $p$, we may deduce $q$,

sometimes known as *modus ponens*.  Another is *modus tollens*:

- given the statement "if $p$ then $q$" and the statement that $q$ is false, we may deduce that $p$ is false.

We would also want it to be *possible in some cases* for "if $p$ then $q$" to be false - not much point discussing it if it is always true.

The only truth table for $p\to q$ which matches our intuitive understanding (in the above sense) is the accepted one.  See Dan's answer for the details.

---

**Addendum**.  After a bit of thought, here is another way of doing it which may be more intuitively appealing.  Our basic intuitive properties of implication are:

- any statement implies itself (so $p\to p$ is always true);
- *modus ponens* is valid (from $p\to q$ and $p$ we can deduce $q$);
- the *converse error* is not valid (from $p\to q$ and $q$ we cannot deduce $p$).

Comment: Have added another idea to my answer.

Comment: from the converse error, shouldn't the implication therefore be false when $p$ is false?

Comment: @emily No.  Because then for $p\to q$ to be true, there would be only one case, namely the case when $p$ and $q$ are both true.  So if you knew $p\to q$ and $q$ were both true, then you could be certain that $p$ was true.  This is the converse error.

Comment: @emily I think you are mixing up "we cannot deduce that $p$ is true" with "we can deduce that $p$ is false".  But these are quite different.  From an intuitive point of view, if we know $q$ is true and if-$p$-then-$q$ is also true, we cannot deduce anything about $p$.  For example, in a "universe" of quadrilaterals, the statement "if ABCD is a square, then ABCD has four equal angles" is true.  Suppose you know that ABCD has four equal angles.  Is it a square? - the answer is, "maybe".  You cannot be sure it is a square, but you cannot be sure it isn't either.  Hope this clarifies the matter.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f_{abcd}(x, y)$ denote a function of two Boolean variables defined by the truth table:

```
 x │ y │ f
───┼───┼───
 0 │ 0 │ a
 0 │ 1 │ b
 1 │ 0 │ c
 1 │ 1 │ d
```

There are 16 possible combinations of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$, defining 16 possible functions.  Let's try to find one such that $f_{abcd}(x, y)$ is as similar as possible to the statement “If $x$, then $y$” under classical rules of logical inference.

### Modus ponens

A syllogism of the form:

1. (premise) If P, then Q.
2. (premise) P.
3. (conclusion) Therefore, Q.

Or, in symbolic notation, $((P \rightarrow Q) \land P) \rightarrow Q$.

(The distinction between $\implies$ and $\rightarrow$ doesn't matter for my purposes here, so I'll use $\rightarrow$ throughout just for aesthetic reasons.)

Or, expressing $\rightarrow$ as a function $f$, then $f(f(P, Q )\land P), Q)$.

Of the 16 possible $f$ functions, four of them satisfy the *modus ponens* law for all possible combinations of P and Q: $f_{1100}$, $f_{1101}$, $f_{1110}$, and $f_{1111}$.  That is, $a$ and $b$ must both be 1, but $c$ and $d$ may be either 0 or 1.

$f_{1101}$, the conventional $\rightarrow$ operator, satisfies *modus ponens*.  But $f_{1001}$ (aka $\leftrightarrow$) does not satisfy it.  Specifically, it fails when $P \oplus Q$.

### Modus tollens

1. (premise) If P, then Q.
2. (premise) Not Q.
3. (conclusion) Therefore, not P.

In symbolic notation, $((P \rightarrow Q) \land \lnot Q) \rightarrow \lnot P$.

In function notation, $f(f(P, Q) \land \lnot Q, \lnot P)$.

This rule is satisfied only by $f_{1101}$ (the conventional $\rightarrow$ operator) and $f_{1111}$ (the constant True function).

### Existence of false conditionals

$\exists P, Q : \lnot(P \rightarrow Q)$.

This rules out $f_{1111}$, but the other 15 functions all qualify.

## Putting it all together

Of the 16 possible ways to define $\rightarrow$ as a function of two Boolean parameters, only one simultaneously satisfies *modus ponens* and *modus tollens* while allowing false conditional statements to exist.

```
 x │ y │ x→y
───┼───┼─────
 0 │ 0 │  1
 0 │ 1 │  1
 1 │ 0 │  0
 1 │ 1 │  1
```

Changing the second row of this table (effectively turning $\rightarrow$ into $\leftrightarrow$) would break both *modus ponens* and *modus tollens*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have not rigorously studied logic. Can you please help me - how to know that those are the only combinations which satisfy modus ponens?

Comment: @YathirajSharma: It's just a matter of calculating the truth tables for $f(f(P, Q )\land P), Q)$ (for modus ponens) and $f(f(P, Q) \land \lnot Q, \lnot P)$ (for modus tollens) with all 16 possible definitions of $f$, and finding the ones that are tautologies (true for all 4 rows of the table).

Comment: Please bear with me. When you said $\textit{satisfy modus ponens}$, did you mean that for those combinations $(P\implies Q) \wedge P)\implies Q$ is a tautology?

Answer (score 1):

> What would have happened if $P \implies Q$ was taken false when $P$ was false and $Q$ was true?

To avoid inconsistencies, at the very least, you would have to invalidate at least one step in the following proof that $\neg P \implies [P \implies Q]:\\$

[image]

(Screenshot from my proof checker)

You might, for example, have to disallow or somehow restrict proof by contradiction (line 5), or elimination of '$\neg\neg$' (line 6).

Comment: I note your sentence is a classical equivalent of explosion. Under OP's changed rule for "$\implies$", can you add a derivation of an inconsistency (contradiction?) from it, which you mention? Secondly, regarding the proof checked program, which I don't know: How/Why does $\neg Q$ appear as assumption in the third line?

Comment: @Nikolaj-K You want to prove $P\implies Q$. You introduce the premise $P$ on line 2, and suppose to the contrary that $\neg Q$ on the next line. You obtain a contradiction on line 4 and conclude $\neg\neg Q$ on line 5, thus discharging the premise on line 3.

Comment: Okay, I see. So it's because it lets you introduce ¬ and then negating it, without in any way using it. Anyway, to the second question - what inconsistency do you mean in the answer?

Comment: @Nikolaj-K If you want to somehow ban the use of vacuous truth, you will have to somehow make it impossible to derive the above result, and perhaps other results as well.

Comment: I'm actually not sure if I follow. What I can say is that the proposition you prove in this answer is not adopted or provable in all [paraconsistent logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic), but I don't at once see why it's not consist with OP's notion of entailment.

Comment: @Nikolaj-K IIUC the OP is suggesting that $\neg P \land Q \implies \neg (P \implies Q)$ be an axiom or theorem of propositional logic. Using the basic rules of logic, however, we can obtain $\neg P \land Q \implies  (P \implies Q)$. These results are not consistent. Can't comment on "paraconsistent" logic.

Comment: Well, OP stated an idea of how entailment could be evaluated. Your syntatic characterization of what he said, as an implication sentence in the object language, $\neg P\land Q\implies \neg(P\implies Q)$, seems tricky. Could OP agree with adopting this sentence as an (always true) axiom, to express his idea of how entailment should be evaluated? I doesn't seem so: Whenever $P$ is true or $Q$ is false, that sentence itself (now of the form $F\implies T$) would have be considered false by OP's idea of how entailment should be evaluated.