# Applying vacuous truths to real-world implications

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Here is an implication that confuses me when I think about it:

$\qquad$ I am holding a pen $\implies$ It is raining outside.

This implication seems to say that it will rain outside whenever I hold a pen.

If I am not holding a pen, the implication is true. But how can this be so if I can just hold a pen and see that it does not rain? My guess is that implications can be true sometimes and false sometimes, so me holding a pen and seeing it does not rain does not prove that the implication is always false. But if this is the case, what does it even mean for the implication to be true, for the times when I do not hold a pen?

$$$$
I can see that the implication

$\qquad$ I am holding a pen $\implies$ *False*,

would be true when I do not hold a pen, even though its consequence is never true. And anytime I hold a pen, the consequence in the implication will be false.

Comment: The pen-rain implication is a poor example of a mathematical statement. It gets very slightly better if we make explicit the implicit quantifier: For all times/places $T$, if I hold a pen at time $T$ then it rains at time $T$. Now the statement is unambiguously false (or else please contact the weather bureau). “If $x$ is odd then $x^2$ is divisible by $3$” is not sometimes true, but rather flatly false since it has an implicit quantifier “for all $x$”.

Comment: In the usual sense of "implies" in mathematics, "I am holding a pen $\implies$ It is raining outside" means only that, at this instant in time, we do not have both "I am holding a pen" being true and "It is raining outside" being false. In mathematics, we do not have the notion of causality or the passage of time. These are in the realm of science. See my answer to a similar problem at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551320/understanding-vacuously-true-truth-table/1551525#1551525

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure other people have said this somewhere on math stackexchange, but reading the proposed duplicate answers, I see plenty of room for confusion, so I think it's probably easiest to just write a clarification here.

The logical definition of implication doesn't really line up with the colloquial definition of implication unless you include a *universal quantifier*.

In your example, we wouldn't colloquially say that the statement "If you are holding a pen, then it is raining outside" is true, even though it is *sometimes* true logically, because what matters is whether or not it's *always* true.

The right way to translate the statement into a logical statement is to say "*At all times*, if you are holding a pen, then it is raining outside." The "at all times" portion of the sentence (which is a universal quantifier) ensures that, in order for the sentence to be true, we are not only interested in now in particular, but rather all possible moments. So to say the statement is false, we only need to find one counterexample - one particular time when you were holding a pen and it was a clear day outside. Which, as you said, can easily be accomplished by simply picking up your pen on a clear day.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The necessity of quantifiers clears up my confusion with non-mathematical implications. I have a follow up question which I guess could apply to any always-false implication. Say, $P \implies Q$, where $P$ varies and $Q$ is always false. If $P$ is false (making the implication true), doesn't that mean $P \land Q$, which can never be true, since $Q$ is always $\lnot Q$?

Comment: $Q$ being false doesn't mean $Q$ is $\neg Q$...

Comment: My mistake. I just mean, $P \land Q$ says $P$ is true and $Q$ is true, but how can this happen if we have established $Q$ to be a statement that is always false, like $1 \neq 1$, for instance.

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting $P \land Q$ from. The statement $P \implies Q$ is equivalent to $\neg P \lor Q$.

Comment: There is no need for "At all times..." Better would be, "At this instant in time..." (See my comment.)

Comment: @DanChristensen I was changing the statement so the mathematical interpretation of the new statement would match the colloquial meaning of "If you are holding a pen, then it is raining outside". It sounds to me like you're changing it so that the colloquial interpretation of the new statement would match the mathematical meaning of "If you are holding a pen, then it is raining outside"?

Comment: @DanChristensen I fail to understand why your approach would help someone understand the reason for the mathematical definition.

Comment: @DanChristensen I added "colloquially" to "we wouldn't say" in my answer, to make it clear that by "we" I mean people generally, not mathematicians/logicians in particular.

Comment: What I described here *is* the mathematical definition. It is explains why,  if $A$ is false, then $A\implies B$ must be true regardless of whether $B$ is true or false. This is a commonly used method of proof in mathematics -- all things follow from a falsehood. Likewise, it explains why, if $B$ is true, then $A\implies B$ must be true regardless of whether $A$ is true or false -- all things imply that which is true. It works.

Comment: @DanChristensen I mean, if you take the attitude that students should just accept a definition without question even if it doesn't make sense up front, sure. I prefer to help make sense of a definition when possible though.

Answer (score 0):

As not so much a proof as an informal justification, let us fill in the truth table for $A\Rightarrow B$. We start with:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\space&A&B&A\Rightarrow B\\\hline
1&T&T&\\
2&T&F&\\
3& F&T&\\
4&F&F&
\end{array}$$

Consider two cases.

**Case 1**

Suppose $A \Rightarrow B$ is true.

Consider two sub-cases.

**Sub-case 1**

Suppose $A$ is true. Since $A \Rightarrow B$ is true, then $B$ must also be true. We can now fill in line 1:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\space&A&B&A\Rightarrow B\\\hline
1&T&T&T\\
2&T&F&\\
3& F&T&\\
4&F&F&
\end{array}$$

**Sub-case 2**

Suppose $A$ is false **(your *vacuous* case)**. The we cannot conclude anything about $B$ from $A \Rightarrow B$. $B$ could be true, or it could be false. We can now fill in lines 3 and 4:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\space&A&B&A\Rightarrow B\\\hline
1&T&T&T\\
2&T&F&\\
3& F&T&T\\
4&F&F&T
\end{array}$$

**Case 2**

Suppose $A\Rightarrow B$ is false. Then $A$ would have to be true and $B$ would have to be false. Now we can fill in the remaining line 2:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\space&A&B&A\Rightarrow B\\\hline
1&T&T&T\\
2&T&F&F\\
3& F&T&T\\
4&F&F&T
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

> what does it even mean for the implication to be true ?

Here are the four types of ‘imply’:

1. $P$ **implies** $R$

   - Some complex number is real **implies** that every positive number is real.
2. **for each** $x, Px$ **implies** $Rx\qquad\leftarrow$*universal implication*

   - **Every** multiple of $6$ **is** even.
3. $P$ **logically implies** $R$

   - $\big(A\to\exists y\,By\big)\,$ **logically implies** $\,\exists y\big(A\to By\big).$
4. $Px$ **logically universally implies** $Rx$

   - $x\not=x\:$ **logically universally implies** $\,Rx.$

(Roughly speaking, a [logical truth](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884853/21813) is a sentence that is true regardless of how its symbols are interpreted. For examples 1 & 2, the context is mathematical analysis.)

> $\qquad$ I am holding a pen $\implies$ It is raining outside.$\qquad(1)$
>
> This implication seems to say that it will rain outside whenever I hold a pen.

No it does not: this Type 1 example is a [synthetic implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4252038/21813) (its specific context might be **right now**, **in Ximending, Taipei**), not an analytic implication or general truth that suggests a prediction or "will / will not".

> me holding a pen and seeing it does not rain does not prove that the implication is always false.

It does: your description means precisely that implication $(1)$ is false.

Which is not to say that it is *logically* false: clearly, it is true in some other scenario/context.

In contrast, the implication

$\qquad$ "I am holding a pen and every empty-handed person is holding no object implies that I am not empty-handed"

is *logically* true (Type 3 above). When you're writing the following and wanting to analyse implications across varying contexts, you are probably thinking of Types 2-4 above, whereas vacuous truth in the context of Type 1 is really just a matter of definition:

> the implication is *always* false

> the implication to be true, *for the times when* I do not hold a pen

> the implication would be true *when* I do not hold a pen

> *anytime* I hold a pen, the consequence in the implication *will be* false.