# A logical implication in which both sides are unrelated

Tags: logic, terminology, definition, predicate-logic

Is this proposition true or not:

$$ \forall x(x=x) \rightarrow \forall x( x^2 -a^2 = (x+a)(x-a))$$

The left side $x=x$ does not have to do anything with the right side $x^2 - a^2 = (x+a)(x-a),$ but they are both true in any case; does this mean that a tautology is implying a tautology, and thus this statement is true?

Comment: How could it be false?

Comment: $A \to B$ is true if when $A$ is true, $B$ is true. As $A$ and $B$ are always true, when $A$ is true we have that $B$ is true and thus $A\to B$.

Comment: Many thanks! I thought it was ridiculous because $A$ has nothing to do with the fact that $B$ is true :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the left-hand side has "nothing to do" with the right-hand side does not matter. Classical logic only cares about truth values, not contextual relevance or causal relation or anything.

The left-hand side is, as you suspect, tautological: There is no way to make it false, no matter which domain of discourse the quantifier ranges over.

The right-hand side is *not* always true. It is true with the standard interpretation of the symbols $+, -, \cdot, ²$, but false if we e.g. were to assign the function symbol $²$ the meaning "square root". When checking for tautologicity, such non-standard interpretations have to be considered as well!

An implication with a tautological antecedent is logically equivalent to the succedent, that is, if the left-hand side is a tautology, the implication as a whole will take the truth value of the right-hand side. Since $\forall x(x=x)$ is tautological, and $\forall x( x^2 -a^2 = (x+a)(x-a))$ is true in the "real world" but false for different interpretations of the symbols, the implication comes out as true, but not tautological.

Comment: @Ryan G Yes, sometimes a distinction is made between tautology and validity/logical truth, and with that distinction, $\forall x (x = x)$ indeed is only valid and not tautological. But some sources treat the two as synonymous, and based on the OP that's what I'm assuming here.

Comment: @Ryan G No, I never talked about *logical* truth, just truth (in the standard model).

Comment: Oh that's right, you were distinguishing plain ol' truths from first-order validities (logical truths). Your responses have been very helpful in evolving my understanding against the sea of conflicting notions, terminology and notation. I shall post a contrasting answer summarising what I've gathered.

Answer (score 1):

Some definitions $\large($**tautology** $\subseteq$ **validity** $\subseteq$ **truth**$\large)$:

- a **tautology** is a formula that is true in its
  truth-functional form regardless of interpretation;
- a **validity** is a formula that is true
  regardless of interpretation;
- a (synthetic or analytic) **truth** is a formula that is true in a particular
  interpretation.

Thus in the given statement $$\forall x \left(x=x\right)\rightarrow \forall x\forall y \left(x^2 -y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)\right),$$

- the antecedent (call it $L$) is **valid** (and therefore
  true in the standard interpretation), but **not tautological**;
- the consequent (call it $R$) is **true in the standard interpretation**, but **neither valid nor tautological**;
- the statement as a whole is **true in the standard interpretation**
  $\left(\text{so we can write }\,L\Rightarrow R\,\right),$ but **neither
  valid nor tautological**.

P.S. I prefer to call $\,\large\rightarrow\,$ the material conditional and $\,\large\implies\,$ the implication symbol. [(Why I don't call $\,\rightarrow\,$ “implication”.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884866/21813)