# Understanding non-truths and writing them as contradictions

Tags: logic

A contradiction is defined as a logical proposition that is always false, such as

$(p \land \neg p) \iff False $

According to my Professor, examples of non-truth are

(1) Assuming that $(p\rightarrow q)$ and $(\neg p \rightarrow \neg q )$ are logically equivalent.

(2) $(\exists u$ $p(u))$ $\land$ $(\exists u$ $q(u))$ $\rightarrow$ $(\exists u$ $(p(u) \land q(u)))$.

So from what I understand, a non-truth is when we make a logical mistake (state a logical equivalence that doesn't exist).
Could we write (1) and (2) this way:

$((p\rightarrow q) \iff (\neg p \rightarrow \neg q )) \iff False$

$[((\exists u$ $p(u))$ $\land$ $(\exists u$ $q(u))$ $\rightarrow$ $(\exists u$ $(p(u) \land q(u)))) \iff (a \rightarrow b)]$  $\iff False$.

edit: I wrote a typo, I meant $(p \land \neg p) \iff False $, not $(p \land \neg q) \iff False $. Very sorry about that.

Comment: @ryang so a contradiction is always false, where as a non-truth is sometimes false, sometimes true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A contradiction is defined as a logical proposition that is always
> false,

The logical proposition ‘I am a swan’ is arguably “always” false, yet it is not a contradiction, because *its truth-functional form* $P$ is sometimes true.

> such as $$(p \land \neg q) \iff\text{False}.$$

We can fully symbolise the above as $$(p \land \neg q) \iff \bot,\tag0$$ where $\bot$ is the standard symbol for contradiction, i.e., $(p\land\lnot p).$

Now, put $(p,q)=(T,F)$ to see that $(p \land \neg q)$ isn't a contradiction. So, $(0)$ is a false assertion.

> According to my Professor, examples of non-truth are
>
> (1) assuming that $(p\rightarrow q)$ and $(\neg p \rightarrow \neg q)$ are logically equivalent

$$(p\rightarrow q)\leftrightarrow(\neg p \rightarrow \neg q)\tag1$$

> (2) $$(\exists u p(u)) \land (\exists u q(u)) \rightarrow (\exists u (p(u) \land q(u)))\tag2$$

Sentences $(1)$ and $(2)$ are indeed **invalid** (what you mean by them being “non-truths”).

Now, put $(p,q)=(T,T)$ to make sentence $(1)$ true!

Next, put $p(u),q(u)=\text‘u$ is a member of the universe’ to make sentence $(2)$ true!

We thus say that these two sentences are **satisfiable**.

> Can we write $$[((\exists u p(u)) \land (\exists u q(u)) \rightarrow (\exists u (p(u) \land q(u)))) \iff (a \rightarrow b)] \iff \text{False}$$

$$\big(\exists u p(u) \land \exists u q(u) \rightarrow \exists u p(u) \land q(u) \big) \leftrightarrow (a \rightarrow b)$$ is neither a contradiction nor even unsatisfiable.

Incidentally, the sentence $(\exists x\:x\ne x)$ is unsatisfiable but not a propositional-logic contradiction.

> Understanding non-truths and writing them as contradictions

Summing up: **an invalid sentence might not be a contradiction nor even unsatisfiable.**

I appreciate that all this can be rather confusing at first; [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4512153/21813), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4252038/21813) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4507714/21813) (and the links within them) could be further reading.

Comment: but doesn't the symbol $\iff$ requires the LHS and RHS to be logically equivalent. In this case, ((→)⟺(¬→¬)) is never true, so it is a contradiction?

Comment: or is this non-truth written with this symbol $\leftrightarrow$. Since we can't say that it is always true, so we can't use this symbol $\iff$. So we use $\iff$ only when it's a tautology, and $\iff F$ when it's contradiction. When it's a non-truth, we use $\leftrightarrow$

Comment: also, a non-truth do not meet the criterion of being a statement right? since it can be both right and wrong?

Comment: 1. Observe that I've demonstrated that your so-called "always true" sentence can be false, and that your so-called "non-truth" can be true; these phrases, especially as we are discussing the ins and outs of logic, are terribly misleading and obfuscating understanding, so you should please stop using them! As you replace them with more accurate terms, the concepts/framework correspondingly make more sense.

Comment: 2. `A↔B` is just a logical expression, and could be a tautology, a contradiction, or anywhere in between those two in "truthiness" (e.g., invalid but satisfiable). No problem to call it a sentence (or statement)! $\tag*{}$ 3. Since your `⟺` means *logical* equivalence (I prefer `≡`, but let's stick to `⟺` ), then the meta sentence $→⟺¬→¬$ is false (don't say "contradiction"), as the biconditional $→↔¬→¬$ isn't *logically* true; however, since I've demonstrated that $(p,q)=(T,T)$ makes the latter true, **neither** sentence should be called a contradiction!

Answer (score 2):

Here (1) and (2) are 'non-truths' because they aren't always true - you can find propositions $p,q$ such that (1) or (2) doesn't hold.

For example if we set

$p=$"$P$ is a rectangle"

$q=$"$P$ is a square", then:

$p \rightarrow q$

doesn't hold, for not all rectangles are squares

$\neg p \rightarrow \neg q$

does hold, because what isn't a rectangle cannot be a square.

We found $p,q$ such that
$$(p\rightarrow q) \iff (\neg p \rightarrow \neg q)$$ does not hold so it's not a tautology - 'truth'. We call such sentences 'non-truths'.

You may convince yourself that the following propositions show, that (2) is a 'non-truth', for the same reason.

$p=$"$P$ is a rectangle with area $u$",

$q=$"$P$ is a square with area $u$".

Now, 'non-truth' isn't necessarily false.
If we take $p=q$ then both (1) and (2) evaluate to true. Basically:

-a tautology is always true

-a falsehood is always false

-a 'non-truth' can go either way

Answer (score 2):

> A contradiction is defined as a logical proposition that is always false.

The keyword is "always".  It means "all truth values we may give to its literals/predicates".

$p\land\neg q$ is *not always* false.   We may value it as true by valuing $p$ as true *and* $q$ as false.

$p\land\lnot p$ is always false, because whatever truth value we give to $p$, we will evaluate $p\land\lnot p$ as false.