# Valuation and truth valuation

Tags: logic

**EDITED to crucially distinguish the book excerpts from the OP's own words.**

---

In Bell-Machover's "A course in Mathematical Logic", on pag. 53 we read:
"the prime formula $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$ is satisfied by any valuation, but not every truth valuation" and '$\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$ is logically true but not tautologically true; and it is logically (but not tautologically) equivalent to $\forall x (\alpha \leftrightarrow \alpha)$'

I don't understand how $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$ can be "not tautologically true". 
It is proven that

> 10.2 Theorem: If $\Phi \vdash_0 \alpha $ then $\Phi \vDash_0 \alpha $. In particular, if  $\vdash_0 \alpha $  then $\vDash_0 \alpha$.

That is, if a proposition is provable (propositionally deducible from the empty set) then it is a tautology;

and that

> 10.3 Lemma: For any $\alpha$, $\vdash_0 (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) $

That is, $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha $ is provable.

Therefore I should conclude that  $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha $ is a tautology (which is clear from the truth table), which means it should be satisfied by any truth valuation. Any truth valuation, though arbitrary, should be by definition compatible with $\neg$  and $\rightarrow$:
$ (\neg \alpha)^\sigma = \top$ iff $(\alpha)^\sigma = \bot \quad $  and   $\quad (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)^\sigma =\top$  iff  $\alpha^\sigma = \bot $ or $\beta^\sigma =\top $

How can therefore a truth valuation give $\bot$ for $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$? I feel like I am missing something important!

Comment: Consider the peculiar choice of the author the use from the start the language of predicate logic (page 15). The propositional part is defined as a "fragment" of it, through *truth valuations* (page 20) that consider only $\lnot$ and $\to$: they do not "see" quantifiers. Thus, a *prime* formula $\forall x \alpha$ (page 21) is considered by truth valuations as a propositional atom $p$ and cannot be a tautology.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA This makes everythig clear. I confused propositional logic and first order logic. $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha $ is a tautology, but $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$ cannot be, because it is considered prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear whether the sentence near the middle of your post is an excerpt or your commentary, but my guess is that Bell-Machover defines a [tautology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507600/can-that-dog-is-a-mammal-be-considered-a-tautology/4507714#comment9464174_4507600) by virtue of its *truth-functional form*; as such, neither $$\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$$ nor $$\forall x (\alpha \leftrightarrow \alpha)$$ nor $$\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)\leftrightarrow \forall x (\alpha \leftrightarrow \alpha)$$ are tautologies, but all are logical truths.

---

**EDIT**

OP:

> Yes, the parts "That is ..." are my remarks.

Yes, I'd guessed that. So, to elaborate: the three formula that I gave above have truth-functional forms $$P$$ and $$Q$$ and $$P\leftrightarrow Q,$$ respectively, so are not (propositional-logic) tautologies.

Comment: Theorems 10.2 and 10.3 are proven in the cited book, pag. 36.

Comment: @britz I wasn't referring to the meat of that theorem, but to (what may be) your commentary within the excerpt. The Google Books preview looks quite different from your excerpt (probably different editions); this reinforces my suspicion that the author's definition of Tautology is as I gave above. $\quad$ **EDIT:** Mauro's new comment above is reinforcing everything I've said. $\quad$ If you wish to edit your Question, I suggest adding block quotes to clearly distinguish what you've excerpted and which lines are your commentary, which may not be consistent with the author's meaning.

Comment: Yes, the parts "That is ..." are my remarks. I'll try to edit the post as you suggested. Sorry, I'm new.