# What does the logical condition "implies" actually mean?

Tags: propositional-calculus

$P_n$ and $Q_n$ are propositions which has a truth value $n$ where $n \in (T,F)$

So i want to access the truth value of $P\Rightarrow Q$

So

$P_T$ and $Q_T$, $(P \Rightarrow Q)_T$

$P_T$ and $Q_F$, $(P \Rightarrow Q)_F$

$P_F$ and $Q_T$, $(P \Rightarrow Q)_T$

$P_F$ and $Q_F$, $(P \Rightarrow Q)_T$

I don't really understand the last 2 statements. Can anyone explain them?

Like for  (2), If P is true then Q is false, then  $P \Rightarrow Q$ is false. that is self evidential. But how about (3) and (4) i can't seem to understand

Comment: About the truth-functional definition of the *connective* $\to$ ("**if ___, then__**"), you can see this [post](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14549/what-is-the-relation-between-the-material-conditional-in-logic-and-conditionals)

Comment: And a bunch of other posts linked from that one.  This is a FAQ. For example, [Truth Table for If P then Q](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168282/truth-table-for-if-p-then-q/) may be useful.

Comment: See also Peter Smith's [hand-out](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/Conditionals.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In propositional calculus the "implies" connector means something a little more technical than implication in the cause and effect sense. It is usually the case that $A\implies B$ is shorthand for $\neg A \lor B$.

Answer (score -1):

It's a definition.

$(P \Rightarrow Q)$ means that either (1), (3) or (4) is true.

In other words, $(P \Rightarrow Q) \leftrightarrow [(P \wedge Q) \vee(\neg P \wedge Q)\vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)]$

As (2), or $(P \wedge \neg Q)$, make (1), (3) and (4) all false, (2) also makes $(P \Rightarrow Q)$ false.