# About the third row in the truth table from the conditional

Tags: logic

I would like to know why is universally accepted by mathematicians and logicians that: if P is false and Q true, then P → Q is true.

Why cannot be otherwise? Which are the reasons?

Comment: This issue has been discussed often here.  Do a search for "If p then q" to get started.

Comment: There is a lot that has been written on this in the intersection of philosophy and logic! http://stanford.library.usyd.edu.au/archives/sum2010/entries/logic-conditionals/

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551320/understanding-vacuously-true-truth-table/1551525#1551525