# Deductive Logic : If A -> B it can be deduced neg(A) -> neg(B)

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I am having a hard time proving the following $$ (a \to b) \vdash (\lnot a \to \lnot b) $$

I followed the book advice and first proved that $ (a \to b) \vdash (\lnot \lnot a \to \lnot \lnot b) $ using the Deduction Theorem but I am stuck afterwards.
 I have been trying to use every Axioms/Modus/Rules I know but always end up with unsatisfactory result.

A hint would be appreciated,

Comment: That's because it's false. It is true that one can infer $\neg b \to \neg a$ from $a \to b$ though (in classical logic anyway).

Comment: For an example of why it is false: If $n$ is a multiple of $10$ then $n$ is also a multiple of $2$.  This is a true statement ($n=10k\Rightarrow n=2\cdot (5k)$).  However, the statement "if $n$ is not a multiple of $10$ then it is not a multiple of $2$" is false.  Take $6$ for a counterexample.  $6$ happens to not be a multiple of $10$ however it is indeed a multiple of $2$.

Comment: See my answer to a similar question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551320/understanding-vacuously-true-truth-table/1551525#1551525

Answer (score 4):

If it is raining, then there are clouds out. ($a\implies b$)

If it is not raining, then there are no clouds out ($\neg a \implies \neg b$)

The first is true and the second isn't. There is something close to what you want, called [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition).