# Understanding contraposition as the invers of implication

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have always thought of implication in the way it is shown here in wikipedia: [Contraposition article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition#Intuitive_explanation)

When I think of the first part of the implication as the violet (sub-)set A and the second part of the implication as the blue (super-)set B then implication makes sense to me.

- Something that isn't contained within A might not be contained in B too. => Right.
- Something that isn't contained within A can still be contained in B. => Right.
- Something is contained in A but not in B doesn't make sense. So therefore implication becomes false.
- Something that is contained in A is contained in B as well. => Right.

That way of thinking has always made sense to me.

Now I have to learn proof by contradiction.

I have got this table as part of my study documents.

[image: Truth table]

I try to understand but no chance.

I mean especially the third row.

If I invers p and q. So that p (which is the subset in my thinking) becomes true and q (which is the superset) becomes false: **How can this be true?**

Wouldn't it say then:

"*It isn't in the superset (q == false) but it is in the subset (p)*"?

Because implication from false to true becomes true implication the result is true.

**But that doesn't make sense to me.**

How can something be part of a subset but not part of the superset?

**Can anybody help me to understand how this table works?**

Respectively: What do I wrong concerning my thinking? Where's my error?

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551320/understanding-vacuously-true-truth-table/1551525#1551525

Comment: Indeed very interesting. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @DanChristensen  I think the link may confuse things. If there were (but there isn't) a column in the truth-table labeled $(p \leftrightarrow q)$, then we would have the last comment in the answer/question you linked to.  As I said, that's not a column here.  Instead, we have the tautology, expressing the truth values of the biconditional involving equivalent statements $(p\to q) \leftrightarrow(\lnot q \to \lnot p)$. And as we can see, it expresses a tautology.  Whenever $p\to q$ is true, so is $\lnot q \to \lnot p$ true.  Whenever, $p\to q$ is false, so is $\lnot q \to \lnot p$.

Comment: Looking at your answer (which you linked to here), is isn't even relevant here.

Comment: It seemed to me that the OP was confused about the notion of material implication among other things. I thought my link might help him to solve his problem at least in part. It is comment after all, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your translation to "It isn't in the superset but it is in the subset" is erroneous.  To complement the logic, you must complement the sets - BOTH of them.  Switch 'inside' with 'outside'.  I.e:

p --> q is "Whatever is INside p, is INside q"

translates to

-q --> -p is "Whatever is OUTside q, is OUTside p"

Comment: Thanks a huge bunch. You definitely saved my day.