# False implies anything

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I understand *Implication*, as follows:

```
p = rain stopped.
q = i go out.

p->q =  if "rain stopped" then "i go out".

p                       q                       p->q
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F                       F                       T
(rain is not stopped)   (i don't go out)        (if rain is not stopped, I don't go out)
F                       T                       F
(rain is not stopped)   (i go out)              (if rain is not stopped, I go out)
T                       F                       F
(rain is stopped)       (i don't go out)        (if rain is stopped, I don't go out)
T                       T                       T
(rain is stopped)       (i go out)              (if rain is stopped, I go out)
```

But, [this video](https://youtu.be/rAxXcX_w5fE?list=PLl-gb0E4MII28GykmtuBXNUNoej-vY5Rz&t=204) says that $F \rightarrow T = T$

Comment: Just because you go out, even when it is raining, does not signify that the statement $(p \implies q)$ is false.  In fact, this situation is actually focusing on the critical difference between the statements $(p \implies q)$ and $(p \iff q)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The fact that the conditional $$P\to Q$$ is true whenever its antecedent $P$ is false ([principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion); [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)) is actually so *by definition*:

   $P\to Q\,$ is a **truth function** that is tautologically equivalent to $\,\lnot P\lor Q.$

   So, $P\to Q\,$ is false *precisely* when $P$ is true but $Q$ false.
2. To be clear: whenever $P$ is false, the assertion $P\implies Q\,$ gives no information about whether $Q$ is true.
3. Summarising [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2724083/21813) [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2723913/21813) explanations of the motivation for the above definition:

   if we insist, to the contrary, that  False$\to$True  be false, then, unfortunately, these violations of natural deduction arise: $$\text{$A$ is true and $B$ is false $\implies\Big[(A\land B)\to A\Big]\;$is false!}$$ and $$\Big[\forall n\in\mathbb Z \;\big(n \text{ is a multiple of }4\, \to \,n \text{ is even}\big)\Big]\;\text{is false}!$$
4. It is worth noting that in logic/mathematics, $P$ need not *cause* $Q$ for $P$ to imply $Q,$ that is, for the material conditional $\,P\to Q\,$ [to actually be true](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3884866/21813).

   After all, the logical connective $\,\to,$ being a truth-functional operator, cares about truth states without considering the flow of time.

Answer (score 0):

Implication $P\Rightarrow Q$ is only false if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false (true premise and wrong conclusion). The video is right.