# Does a statement p that's always false imply that p implies any statement q?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

##### Question

Is the following statement true?

For all statements `p`, `p` always being false implies that for all statements `q`, `p` implies `q`, i.e:

$$\forall p(\lnot p \implies \forall q(p \implies q))$$

If so, why? If not, why not?

Thanks.

---

##### Attempt

Here's my attempt of explaining why I think that the above statement is true. I am new to this notation, so pardon me if I made any mistakes.

**Assumption 1:**

For all statements `p`, `p` does not imply `q` when there exists a statement `r`, where `r` implies `p` but also implies `not q`.

$$\forall p(p \nRightarrow q) \equiv \exists r((r \implies p) \land (r \implies \lnot q))$$

**Assumption 2:**

If we've disproven that `p` does not imply `q`, then `p` implies `q`.

$$\lnot(p \nRightarrow q) \implies (p \implies q) $$

**Proof:**

$p$ is always false, therefore there does not exist $r$ such that $r \implies p$

Therefore, there does not exist $r$ such that $(r \implies p) \land (r \implies \lnot q)$

Therefore, based on *assumption 1* above, the statement $p \nRightarrow q$ is false

Therefore, based on *assumption 2* above, $p \implies q$

However, my two assumptions could be wrong! It's also messy that I am defining logic using logic.

---

##### Context

Here is a proof I was told for the following statement in relation to sets, which goes on the assumption that my statement at the beginning of this post is true.

Statement to prove:

$$\forall A(\emptyset \subset A)$$

A definition for sets:

$$A \subset B \equiv \forall a(a \in A \implies a \in B)$$

Proof:

$$\emptyset \subset A \equiv \forall x(x \in \emptyset \implies x \in A)$$

$x \in \emptyset$ is never true, therefore, based on the statement at the beginning of this post, $x \in \emptyset \implies b \in \emptyset$ is always true, therefore $\emptyset \subset A$

Comment: Yes. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: @AdamRubinson Great, thanks! I really appreciate it!

Comment: An alternative approach is to  construct  a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

Comment: Your translations aren't quite correct; e.g., the first one ought to be $\forall p\bigg( \lnot p \implies \big(\forall q( p \implies q)\big)\bigg)$ instead. Are you using $\equiv$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ synonymously? Related: [False implies anything](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4217336/21813)

Comment: Yes, $\lnot p \to (p \to q)$ is a tautology (check it with truth table).

Comment: But it is not correct to say that $\lnot p$ represent a statement that is always false. A contradiction, like $p \land \lnot p$ is always false. In prop logic we can symbolize with [$\bot$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_(logic)) a statement that is always false.

Comment: Regarding $\emptyset \subseteq A$, for every $A$, your argument is correct.

Comment: @RyanG Thanks for the link to that related post.

Comment: @RyanG Yes I am using $\equiv$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ synonymously. See "material equivalence" in [this section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols#Basic_logic_symbols).

Comment: @RyanG Thanks for the suggestions to improve my notation.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any propositions $P$ and $Q$, here is the truth table for $P\to (\neg P \to Q)$

[image]

Source: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html

Here a proof using a form of natural deduction. For any propositions $P$ and $Q$, we have:

[image]

Source: Screenshot from my proof checker