# I don't understand the truth table for logical consequence $(a \rightarrow b)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

When I take a look at the truth table for implification, I don't get the logic:

```
a     b       a --> b
----------------------
1     1         1
1     0         0
0     1         1
0     0         1
```

I understand implication $a \rightarrow b$ means that $a$ becomes $b$ or I understand this wrong now? Because if I compare what I said with the table, it seems contradicting... My understanding works for all lines except for the last one where we have 0 0 1..

Anyone could please explain me?

Comment: Yes, you understand it wrong. The correct wording is "if $a$, then $b$".

Comment: $a\to b$ is just a typographic variant of $a\Rightarrow b$, meaning "if $a$ then $b$". There is no _becoming_.

Comment: Ok but how would you explain this "if $a$ then $b$" with that table? I don't get why if $a=0$, $b=0$ we have that $a\rightarrow b$ is $1$

Comment: For instance, it is arguably true that, if the moon were made of cheese, famine would not be a severe issue. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @cnmesr: See [In classical logic, why is $p\to q$ True if both $p$ and $q$
are False?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false)

Comment: Alright this is more complicated than I expected : / But thank you a lot for the link. I guess I have to live with the easy reasoning mentioned in your link: "the short answer is that if $a=0$, then it doesn't matter what $b$ is"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbol $\rightarrow$ is read "implies", not "becomes".  Yes, logical implication is an interesting one.  The source of confusion is case 2), below.

Think of an insurance policy.  Let $a$ mean "an accident has occurred", and $b$ "the insurance company has paid out."  Then $(a \rightarrow b)$ means "the insurance company has kept within its contract."  Let's examine the possibilities:

1) $a = F$ (no accident occurred), $b = F$ (no payout made).  The company has kept with the contract, so $(a \rightarrow b) = T$.

2) $a = F$ (no accident occurred), $b = T$ (payout made).  The company would be crazy to do this (pay when it doesn't have to), but would still be within the contract, so $(a \rightarrow b) = T$.

3) $a = T$ (accident occurred), $b = T$ (payout made).  The company has met its contract: $(a \rightarrow b) = T$.

4)  $a = T$ (accident occurred), $b = F$ (no payout made).  Contract violated: $(a \rightarrow b) = F$.

Comment: Thank you a lot I had to read your answer 3 times and then I understood :P Still this is very mean thing to understand!

Comment: Well, you rose to the challenge.:)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than "$a$ becomes $b$", it should be read as "$a$ implies $b$".

The only "disproof" that $a$ implies $b$ is if $a$ is true, but $b$ is not.  That's why only the second row in your table has a false value for $a\to b$.