# What is a piecewise function in set theory (or alternative ways to describe piecewise functions)?

Tags: functions, notation, definition

I have searched, but I haven't found an answer to this question. How are piecewise functions defined in set theory? And what are alternative ways to represent them?

Let's say we have a piecewise function $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$, that is defined by the equation

$$ f(x)=
 \begin{cases} 
      x & x \in [0,3] \\
      3 & x \in (3,8] \\
      x^2 & x \in (8,\infty) 
\end{cases}
$$

The graph of this function is the set

$$ \text{graph } f= \{ (x,y) \mid y=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}_+ \}, $$

but how can I write out this set "graph $f$" using information from the above equation? My quess would be something like this:

$$ \{ (x,y) \mid (x\in[0,3] \rightarrow y=x) \text{ or } (x \in (3,8] \rightarrow y=3) \text{ or } (x \in (8,\infty) \rightarrow y=x^2) \} $$

Is there anything else to know about piecewise functions in set theory, other than the function's graph?

Comment: Many authors distinguish between the two arrows $\to,\mapsto.$ The function $x\mapsto x^2$ is the function whose output is the square of its input. But $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is how the other arrow is used. The "guess" should use the arrow in $x\mapsto x^2,$ not the one in $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R. \qquad$

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean with this. Piecewise functions are not particularly special, and the 'general' definition of $\text{graph} f$ you used works just fine. If what you wanted to is write the graph as a union of smooth graphs, then I guess you're on the right track. The only problem here seems to be an incorrect use of the logical operator $\rightarrow$ ('implies'); it should most definitely be a $\land$ ('and') here.

Comment: Logically the arrows should be replaced by "and" or by "\land".

Comment: @MichaelHardy In those set definitions I use implication arrows on purpose. Using those "function definition" arrows would be clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a practical notation I'll recommend MPW's suggestion. But note that your proposal
$$ \{ (x,y) \mid (x\in[0,3] \rightarrow y=x) \lor (x \in (3,8] \rightarrow y=3) \lor (x \in (8,\infty) \rightarrow y=x^2) \} $$
will *not* work -- that expression will in fact produce all of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.

Namely, no matter what $x$ is, one of $x\in[0,3]$ and $x\in(3,8])$ will be *false*. And since an implication [is always true when the antecedent is false](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false), this means that at least one of the claims you're putting "or" between will be true no matter what $x$ and $y$ are.

If you want to write the set in this style it should be either
$$ \{ (x,y) \mid (x\in[0,3] \land y=x) \lor (x \in (3,8] \land y=3) \lor (x \in (8,\infty) \land y=x^2) \} $$
or
$$ \{ (x,y) \mid (x\in[0,3] \rightarrow y=x) \land (x \in (3,8] \rightarrow y=3) \land (x \in (8,\infty) \rightarrow y=x^2) \} $$

Answer (score 6):

How about just
$$\Gamma_f = \{ (x,x):0\leq x \leq 3\} \cup \{ (x,3): 3<x\leq 8\} \cup \{ (x,x^2):x>8\}$$