# Proof of statement with empty hypothesis

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Let's say I have these two propositions:

**Prop A**. "If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2=-1$ then $3x^2$ is invertible (that means, $3x^2 \neq 0$)"

**Prop B**. "If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2=-1$ then $3x^2$ is singular (not invertible)"

I want to ask about the correctness of these proofs:

**Proof 1.A and 1.B**:  There is no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 = -1$, so no matter what the thesis says, the proposition is true, as there will be no counterexample.

**Proof 2.A**: Suposing $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 = -1$, we have that $3x^2 = 3(-1) = -3 \neq 0$, so proposition $A$ is true.

**Proof 3.B**: Suposing $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 = -1$, we have that $3x^2 = 3(-1) = -3 \neq 0$, so $3x^2$ is not singular and proposition $B$ is false.

Obviously, they can not all be right.  I think Proof 3.B is wrong.  ¿But is proof 2.A right?  Because it's basically using the same method (ignoring that no such $x$ exists, and using the hypothesis)

Comment: All of them are right. If $\neg p$ is true then $p\to q$ and $p\to\neg q$ are true.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but this looks related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2723860/42969

Comment: proof 3 can not be right, it says the proposition is false!

Comment: @dami And? Why shouldn't say that?

Comment: because everyone is saying both propositions are true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the propositions mean "For all $x$, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that ..."  If so, then to prove that Proposition B is false you would have to prove that there exists some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 = -1$ and $3x^2$ is not singular.  Proof 3.B does not do that.  So the final phrase "and Proposition B is false" is incorrect.

Comment: I see.  But is proof 2 right?  It doesn't take into account that there is no x.

Comment: I am acepting this answer, as I don't think noone else is going to reply, and I think proof 2 is also ok, because if q is true then (p implies q) is true, and it has proved q to be true

Comment: Yes, proof 2 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are right. If $\neg p$ is true then $p\to q$ and $p\to\neg q$ are true.

*Example*: If $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $x^2=-1$ then I have tons of umbrellas within a bottle of coke that is in the orbit of Mars. Indeed, assume the contrary. Then, by hypothesis, there exists some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $x^2=-1$. But this is a contradiction, because no such real number exists. So if $x^2=-1$, that thing about the umbrellas is true.

Comment: I know, so proof 1 is correct.  But is proof 2 correct? And why proof 3 is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$\neg P$ and $P$ $\implies Q $ for any propositions $P$ and $Q$ this is known as the principle of explosion .