# Tautology in case $F \to F$

Tags: logic

I have searched and find this:

In classical logic, why is $(p \Rightarrow q) = T$ if $p = F$ and $q = F$?

Is the only way to prove that is not  a tautology by having $T \to F$, which gives $F$?

Comment: oups i did wrong

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Yes, the only way $p\implies q$ can be false is if $p$ is true and $q$ is false; phrased differently, the sentence $$\neg(p\implies q)\iff \neg p\wedge q$$ is a tautology. *(Here "$\wedge$" means "and" and "$\neg$" means "not," and they each bind more tightly than $\iff$.)* Is there anything in the answers to the [previously-linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false) which is unclear? If so, what? (If not, then what remains unclear? Is there an issue with any of the remaining three options?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber thank you a lot,you are clear.I understand it,cause the previous is telling a lot and it is confusing. A line like this is understandable.I thought for example False->False it may be produce False as result,but i see it on the truth table that False ->False gives True and i asked my self.I get influenced by F^F=F

Answer (score 2):

$p{\implies}q$ promises that $q$ will be true if $p$ is.   This promise is only broken (falsified) when $q$ is false when $p$ is true.   When $p$ and $q$ are both false we can not say the promise is not kept.

"$q$ actually is false, but I may still promise it would be true if $p$ were, although it happens to be that $p$ is not."

---

PS: We do not say $p{\implies}q$ is a *tautology* when $p$ and $q$ are false; we just say it is true.   A tautology is true for *all* possible evaluations for the literals.

However, $\bot{\implies}\bot$ *is* a tautology, since the only literals are the falsity constant whose only permissable evaluation is false.