# Is the relation $a^2 +b^2 =0$ transitive?

Tags: equivalence-relations

A relation on the real numbers is given by $a^2 +b^2 =0$. I know this is not reflexive, I believe it is symmetric(although there is only one solution) but I'm not sure whether it can be called transitive as the only solution is $a=b(=0)$.

Comment: If the relation is $a$ ~ $b$ if $a^2+b^2=0$, then as you noted if $a$ ~ $b$ and $b$ ~ $c$ then $ a = b = 0$ and $ b = c = 0$ so $a^2 + c^2 = 0^2 + 0^2 = 0$ thus $a$ ~ $c$, so it is transitive.

Comment: What is $a$ and $b$ here @anushuman .

Comment: Thanks anshuman. You can consider @tanny comment. As long as real numbers are concerned only 0R0 is possibility. So others two relation except reflective is true here

Comment: Per the comment of @AmitMittal, the transitivity breaks down when $a,b,c$ are permitted to be complex numbers.  Example: $a = i, b = 1, c = i.$  Then $a^2 + b^2 = (-1) + (1) = 0$.  Similarly, $b^2 + c^2 = 0.$  However, $a^2 + c^2 = -2.$

Comment: In the question, a and b are to be real numbers (.. Is a relation on the set of real numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the "the relation is transitive" is

> For all $a, b, c$ it holds that if $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then $a\sim c$.

The "if" and "then" here are supposed to be understood in the particular mathematical jargon (known as a "material conditional") where their meaning is that whenever you have a situation where [$a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$] is *false*, [that alone will cause](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false/48202) the whole if-then claim to be considered *true*.

That is completely the case for your relation. Some examples:

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline a & b & c & a \sim b\text{ and }b\sim c? & a \sim c? & \text{so, are we happy?} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & \text{yes} & \text{yes} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & \text{no: }b\sim c\text{ is false} & \text{no} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 2 & \text{no, neither} & \text{no} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
0 & 5 & 0 & \text{no, neither} & \text{yes} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

The one combination that *can't possibly* arise is
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline a & b & c & a \sim b\text{ and }b\sim c? & a \sim c? & \text{so, are we happy?} \\ \hline
?? & ?? & ?? & \text{yes} & \text{no} & \textbf{no} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
and since that is impossible, your relation is transitive.

---

For what's worth, there's a similar variety of intermediate results when we check whether $<$ is transitive -- which it had better be, since it's one of the ur-examples of transitive relations:

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline a & b & c & a < b\text{ and }b < c? & a < c? & \text{so, are we happy?} \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & \text{yes} & \text{yes} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
3 & 2 & 1 & \text{no, neither} & \text{no} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & \text{no: }a<b\text{ is false} & \text{yes} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

But there's no requirement that all three situations in fact arise. For example the relation *that never holds* is transitive, since the only situation we can get is

$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline a & b & c & a \sim b\text{ and }b\sim c? & a \sim c? & \text{so, are we happy?} \\ \hline
\text{whatever} & \text{whatever} & \text{whatever} & \text{no, neither} & \text{no} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

And the relation *that relates everything to everything* is also transitive since for it we end up with
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline a & b & c & a \sim b\text{ and }b\sim c? & a \sim c? & \text{so, are we happy?} \\ \hline
\text{whatever} & \text{whatever} & \text{whatever} & \text{yes} & \text{yes} & \text{yes} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I've only recently learnt about types of relations so I was somewhat confused but going through your comment a few times I got it. Although I have one more type of question I'm unsure about ( I think you answered a similar question in your comment but I'll ask anyway as I'm not sure they're the same) if a relation is such that  if a is related to b, then b can't be related to any other element, ex:- R = {(x, y) : y=x+5 and x<4 } is a relation on N. I initially thought it is not transitive but in the answers it is given to be transitive, but online ncert solutions said it is not

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal: "a relation is such that if a is related to b, then b can't be related to any other element" will necessarily be transitive because this condition says that "$a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$" is _always false_ when $b\ne c$, so we'll always be happy in that case. The desription leaves open the possibility that $b\sim b$ might happen, but if/when that is the case, "$a\sim b$ and $b\sim b$" obviously still implies $a\sim b$, so we're still good.

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal i am being fan of your struggle and self learning habit. Let me clear to you. ( X , Y ) is set of ordered pair where X is a natural number less than 4. So x can be 1 , 2 , 3. And $Y$ is always greater than x by 5. So possible values of $Y$ corresponding to $X$ is 6 , 7 , 8 . So what are the possible order pair comes , let's count : 1). If x is 1 , y is 6 : so , (1 , 6 ) is first ordered pair . 2). If x is 2 , y is 7 : ( 2 ,7 ) . 3). Similarly ( 3 , 8 ) is last one. So it's not reflective , symmetric . But it's transitive

Comment: because 2 related 7 but 7 isn't related to anything then and it's happening with every element so , as per @Troposphere explained if there was 2R7 and 7 was also related to some other no. X then 2 must be related to X for fulfilling the transitivity case. But here b is not related to anything for all b so transitivity is naturally here

Comment: Ok, so I learned a bit more, is this question related to Vacuous Truth?