# Is $\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}$ and $\varnothing\subseteq \{\varnothing\}?$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}$ and $\varnothing\subseteq \{\varnothing\}?$

As per me yes they are true because, in the first statement, the set $\{\varnothing\}$  contains one single element, $\varnothing$, the empty set.

In the second statement because of the fact that an empty set is a subset of every set

What about $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq \varnothing$ ?

Comment: How many elements $\{\emptyset\}$ has?

Comment: As you already said: $\{\emptyset\}$ contains $1$ element. $\emptyset$ contains no elements.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank You
Was unaware about this 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by definition $\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}$—the notation $\{\varnothing\}$ represents the set that contains the empty set (and no other element). And it is also true that $\varnothing\subseteq\{\varnothing\}$. This is because $A\subseteq B$ is just an abbreviation of
$$
\forall x:x\in A\implies x\in B \, .
$$
Therefore, the claim that $\varnothing\subseteq\{\varnothing\}$, by definition means
$$
\forall x:x\in\varnothing\implies x\in\{\varnothing\} \, .
$$
Recall that an implication $p\implies q$ is always satisfied when $p$ is false (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false)). Since the empty set is, well, empty, there is no value of $x$ for which $x\in\varnothing$ is true. Hence, the claim$$\forall x:x\in\varnothing\implies x\in\{\varnothing\}$$ follows immediately. This is known as a [*vacuous* truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). Note that exactly the same argument can be used to prove that the empty set is a subset of *any* given set.

As for $\{\varnothing\}\subseteq \varnothing$, this claim is not true. To prove this, consider that the negation of $$\forall x:x\in\{\varnothing\}\implies x\in\varnothing$$ is $$\exists x:x\in\{\varnothing\}\land x\notin\varnothing \, .$$The above statement is true because $\varnothing\in\{\varnothing\}$ and $\varnothing\not\in\varnothing$.

Comment: Very well explained...Thank You so much 

Comment: No worries, @AyushSambher! Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

The only subset of $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$. If $A\subseteq\emptyset$ and $A$ has an element $a$, then $a$ must also be an element of $\emptyset$.

Comment: Cool Thank You 

Answer (score 2):

The empty set is a subset of every set. Hence $\varnothing \subseteq \{\varnothing\}=:S$. The only element of $S$ is $\varnothing$ by inspection. Hence $\varnothing\in S$. Note that $S$ has one element whereas $\varnothing$ has none; hence $S\not\subseteq \varnothing$, since, otherwise, $S=\varnothing$.

Comment: Got it thanks 

Answer (score 2):

Use $\{\}$ instead of $\emptyset$ and everything will become clear.

- $\{\} \in \{\{\}\}$ true
- $\{\} \in \{\}$ false
- $\{\} \subseteq \{\}$ true
- $\{\} \subseteq \{\{\}\}$ true
- $\{\{\}\} \subseteq \{\}$ false

Comment: Indeed! Thank You 