# Questions about logic and proof systems

Tags: logic, provability

I encountered two similar expressions when prooving two sets A and B are equivalent.

For $A \subseteq B$, we have two ways to prove?

$\forall x \in A$, then $x \in B$

$\forall(x \in A \longrightarrow x \in B)$

1. Are these two ways both right?

2.how to deal with the situation when A is $\varnothing$ coz in the first way we suppose $A$ is not empty?

Appreciate for your helping hands.

Comment: You do not need quantifiers here. Just show $x\in A\implies x\in B$. This is only satisfied if the implication holds for all $x$ and also covers the empty set - case.

Comment: The statement $\forall x \in A, x \in B$ is just a short hand for $\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$.

Comment: "coz in the first way we suppose $A$ is not empty?" No, we don't. It works just fine for empty sets too.

Comment: To see that it works fine for $A = \varnothing$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48202/442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both conditions mean that $\forall x(x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B)$.
Forall and  implication  belong together im math.  formulations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem with the empty set; this is because $p\implies q$ is true whenever $p$ is false, so if $A=\varnothing$ then $x\in A$ is false and because of what I said above we have that the empty set is a subset of every set!

Comment: $\forall x \in$ A as a statement of $x$, how can we know its true value. If I plug into a value say 3, $\forall 3 \in$ A, is it true?