# Conditional statement logic

Tags: logic

Reading from “Introduction to Graph Theory” by Douglas West. In appendix A.22 he remarks:

“A conditional statement is false when and only when the hypothesis is true and the conclusion is false. Thus the meaning of P—> Q is (not P) or Q; the two are logically equivalent. *Every conditional statement with a false hypothesis is true, regardless of whether the conclusion is true.*”

Using truth tables, I can see the logical equivalence. But I am a bit confused by the result.

For example, consider the claim:

“If black is blue, then marble is wood”

How can we see this to be a true statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In classical logic, why is $(p\Rightarrow q)$ True if both $p$ and $q$ are False?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/in-classical-logic-why-is-p-rightarrow-q-true-if-both-p-and-q-are-false). Your question is a recurrent one.

Comment: Are you perhaps subconsciously wishfully conflating $P{\implies}Q$ and $Q\;?$ In other words, writing down your desired truth value of  $P{\implies}Q$ corresponding to each of the four $(P,Q)$ permutations, does the answer in every case correspond to the truth value of $Q\:?$